# Java Lambda - Better Way To Find Extreme Values Of Triangle Containing Vector3D Instances

Tags: java, vector, lambda, compare, java-stream

A triangle polygon has an array `vertices` holding 3x`Vector3D` instances. A method should find the extreme value (min/max) on an axis (x, y or z) for the triangle.

E.g. the triangle `A(0, 0, 3) B(1, 2, 3) C(2, 2, -4)` has a min value of `-4` on the z-axis.

The current implementation looks like this:

```
   public class Triangle implements Iterable<Vector3D> {
        private final Vector3D[] vertices;
        private final double kEpsilon = 1e-8;

        public Triangle(Vector3D... vertices) {
            Preconditions.checkArgument(vertices.length == 3);
            this.vertices = vertices;
        }

        public double getExtremeValueForAxis(int axis) {
            var minimum = getValueByAxisIndex(Arrays.stream(vertices).min((v, vOther) -> {
                var vValueOnAxis = getValueByAxisIndex(v, axis);
                var vOtherValueOnAxis = getValueByAxisIndex(vOther, axis);
                return Double.compare(vValueOnAxis, vOtherValueOnAxis);
            }).get(), axis);
            return minimum;
        }

        private static double getValueByAxisIndex(final Vector3D vertex, final int axis) {
            switch(axis) {
                case 0: return vertex.getX();
                case 1: return vertex.getY();
                case 2: return vertex.getZ();
                default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Axis needs to be in 3D space!");
            }
        }
  }
```

How can I enable the user to search for min/max value by passing a function `Optional<T> min(Comparator<? super T> comparator);` or `Optional<T> max(Comparator<? super T> comparator);` to avoid a boolean flag (e.g. `boolean searchForMin`) and how can I reduce the overall complexity of my implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function and its calls can really be simplified by letting the caller choose both the comparator (reducer in this case) and the axis using functions:

```
/** valueFunction selects the axis 
    reducer selects which of 2 values to retain (max/min in this case)*/
public double getExtremeValueForAxis(
   Function<Vector3D, Double> valueFunction, BinaryOperator<Double> reducer) {
     return Arrays.stream(vertices)
              .map(valueFunction)
              .reduce(reducer)
              .get();
}
```

This can then be called as simply as:

```
new Triangle().getExtremeValueForAxis(Vector3D::getX, Math::max); //max by axis 0
new Triangle().getExtremeValueForAxis(Vector3D::getY, Math::min); //min by axis 1
```

Of course, inline reducers and mappers can also be provided using lambda expressions:

```
new Triangle().getExtremeValueForAxis(v -> v.getY(), 
            (n1, n2) -> n1 > n2 ? n2 : n1); //min by axis 0
```

Comment: Using a lambda expression like `(n1, n2) -> n1 > n2 ? n2 : n1` is not recommended, as it has no clear policy regarding *NaN* values. In contrast, `Math::min` has a documented policy regarding *NaN*; if any value is *NaN*, the result will be *NaN*, so you’re able to spot any error.

Answer (score 1):

I would to map the items in the Stream to `int` first with [`mapToInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and then use the method [`min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#min--) to get the minimum value. This method requires no parameters since it works with [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) instead and integers are compared directly.

```
int minX = Arrays.stream(vertices).mapToInt(Vector3D::getX).min().getAsInt();
int minY = Arrays.stream(vertices).mapToInt(Vector3D::getY).min().getAsInt();
int minZ = Arrays.stream(vertices).mapToInt(Vector3D::getZ).min().getAsInt();

int min =  Arrays.asList(minX, minY, minZ).stream().mapToInt(i -> i).min().getAsInt();
```

Alternatively, concatenate all the values into one List and perform the Stream operations on it:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.stream(vertices).forEach(i -> { 
    integers.add(i.getX()); integers.add(i.getY()); integers.add(i.getZ());
});
int min = integers.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).min().getAsInt();
```

Comment: I've tested it with `mapToDouble` and `getAsDouble` instead of `mapToInt` and `getAsInt()`. But this still doesn't solve the issue that I want a function parameter in the method  `getExtremeValueForAxis` so that when calling the function you can specify if you want to call `.min()`, `.max()`, `.avg()` etc... without writing 3 or more methods.

Comment: I can't picture how your expected comparison would look like. Would you draft an approximate result of the method calls etc.?

Comment: Ty for helping - take a look at the answer provided by Ernest Kiwele this will give you a picture of how I wanted the solution to work

Comment: I got it now. :))